# having issue in lightning:input, using this button for uploading file, and want to set null in button without refreshing page after class response

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, salesforce-id, javascript-controller, helper

.cmp

```
<lightning:textarea name="description"
                            required="true"
                            label="Description"
                            value="{!v.descrption_1}"/>

    <lightning:input aura:id="fileId1" 
                         onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange1}"                                          
                         type="file" 
                         name="file" 
                         label=""
                         accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
                         multiple="false" 
                         disabled="{!v.isHide}"

                         />
```

.js

```
helper.uploadHelper(component, event,component.find("fileId1").get("v.files")[0], i,component.get("v.descrption_1"));
```

.js helper

```
 action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var resp = response.getReturnValue();
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") 
        {
          
            alert("1st Uploaded Successfully"); 
              //here in description i am inserting null
            component.set("v.descrption_1", "");
            //similarly i want fileId1 to be empty after success response but its not working
            component.find("fileId1").set("v.files", "");
             //also i have tried many options like below
             component.find("fileId1").set("v.files", []);


           
        } 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: Have you tried `component.find("fileId1").set("v.value", "");`?

Comment: yes, I have tried this as well but didn't work.

Comment: The issue is I just have to set null in that button so if in any case the button is clicked after inserting the file then it should not insert the previous file rather it shows "insert file" and that would happen just in null condition. apart from this, any other method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of really "stubborn" components that don't want to reset properly, you can always choose to unrender them and then rerender them.

```
<aura:attribute name="showFileDialog" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showFileDialog}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="fileId1" 
                     onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange1}"                                          
                     type="file" 
                     name="file" 
                     label=""
                     accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
                     multiple="false" 
                     disabled="{!v.isHide}"

                     />
</aura:if>
```

---

```
    if (state === "SUCCESS") 
    {
      component.set("v.descrption_1", "");
      component.set("v.showFileDialog", false);
      setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(
          function() {
            component.set("v.showFileDialog", true);
          }
        )
      );
    }
```

Where `$A.getCallback` is used for non-event-driven life cycle reentry, setTimeout is used only to force the smallest possible time for `aura:if` to destroy the old component. By doing this, we reset the internal state of the component to its default values, which should suffice for your purposes.